# Granting offline_access, read_stream, and publish_stream from facebook IFRAME app

Tags: facebook, iframe, permissions

Does anyone know a simple way to grant extended permissions from a canvas page that is rendered as an Iframe in facebook?

I have tried facebook connect and that does not seem to work so now I am trying XFBML but for some reason when I use the prompt-permission attribute it does not open dialogs for the extended permissions that I am requesting. It only opens one dialog and does not behave the way prompt-permission behaves when the canvas is rendered as FBML.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i have no experience with IFrame Apps so i cannot give any advice on the Dialog bug. You used FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog correct?

My Tip: 
Try using http://www.facebook.com/authorize.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=1.0&ext_perm=PERMISSION_NAME

Docu: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions